# Examples of self-adjoint operators on $L^2(\mu)$

Tags: analysis, functional-analysis, mathematical-physics

I'd like to come up with a number of simple examples of (formally) self-adjoint operators on 
$L^2(\mu)$, where $L^2(\mu)$ denotes $L^2(\mathbb R)$ with respect to the Gaussian measure $d\mu$

$$d\mu(x) = \frac{1}{\sqrt{π}} e^{−x^2} dx.$$

So far I have these:

(1) $A$, where $A f(x) = f''(x) - x f'(x)$  $\hspace{5mm}$ (Ornstein-Uhlenbeck),

(2) $B$, where $B f(x)= x f(x)$ $\hspace{5mm}$ (position ),

(3) $C$, where $C f(x) = i f'(x)$ $\hspace{5mm}$ (momentum ).

but would like to add at least a few more.

Any related comments/corrections/references very welcome too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're only interested in formally selfadjoint, then
\begin{align}
          L & = e^{x^2}\left[-\frac{d}{dx}p(x)\frac{d}{dx}\right]+q(x) \\
            & = -pe^{x^2}\frac{d^2}{dx^2}-p'e^{x^2}\frac{d}{dx}+q
\end{align}
for real functions $p$, $q$. For example, if $p=e^{-x^2}$, then
$$
                 L = -\frac{d^{2}}{dx^2}+2x\frac{d}{dx}+q
$$
I think your example (1) may have been generated with weight $e^{-x^2/2}$ instead of $e^{-x^2}$.

A first order operator that is formally selfadjoint is
$$
                 M = e^{x^2}\left[i\frac{d}{dx}\right]+r
$$

Comment: Thanks, yes, you are right about the weight.

Comment: Also, are there any simple non differential operators that immediately come to mind?

Comment: @Hamton : If you choose any orthonormal basis of $L^2_{e^{-x^2}}$ such as normalized Hermite Polynomials $\{ p_n \}$, you can define $Af=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\alpha_n(f,p_n)_{w}p_n$ for any sequence of real numbers $\{ \alpha_n \}$, where $(\cdot,\cdot)_w$ is your weighted inner product. Every such $A$ is at least densely-defined and selfadjoint (not just formally selfadjoint.)